# Starting a program in screen (linux) using golang

Tags: linux, go, exec, gnu-screen

I want to start a .exe file in linux inside a golang project using os/exec library.
I usually use "mono" to start .exe file so i did:

```
command := make([]string, 7)
command = {"screen", "-S", screenName, "-d", "-m", "mono", exeFile}
cmd := exec.Command(command[0], command[1:]...)
cmd.Dir = "ConsoleClient"
_, err := cmd.Output() //*
```

I cant run this and i tried also with `cmd.Run()` or `cmd.Start()`

*With `cmd.Start()` (for me the best way) i don't see any error but at the end screen isn't created

It failed also adding `^M` at the end of my `command`

Comment: `screen` is a terminal management application.   What do you hope to accomplish here, running `screen` from `os/exec`?  By the way, `.exe` is purely a dos/windows thing, absent from posix-land.

Comment: @DanielFarrell if u do "screen" inside your terminal, u can run a screen. i want to create a screen and execute a .exe inside it. To execute a .exe file i always used "mono-runtime", it works fine. To execute a command without join in your screen u need to put screen -d -m <command>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at line 2:

```
command = {"screen", "-dmS", screenName, "mono", exeFile}
```

parameters should be before the screen name.